# Javascript module pattern, where do the private variables go?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern

I'm working on implementing the Javascript module pattern, and I understand how to use it pretty well. What I don't understand is the concept of what happens to the private variables and methods once the function has run and the return value been assigned.

If I have a module like so:

```
var myModule = (function() {

var privateVar1, privateVar2 = 10, privateLogger, privateHello;

privateLogger = function(someInput) {
    console.log(someInput);
};
privateHello = function() { console.log('Hello World!');}

  return {
    publicVar: 'myName',
    publicCounter: 0,
    publicIncrementor: function(bar) {
        bar++;
        privateLogger(bar);
        privateHello();
    }
  }
})();
console.log(myModule);
console.log(myModule.publicIncrementor.toString());
```

When I run the file, I then get an output of:

```
{ publicVar: 'myName',
  publicCounter: 0,
  publicIncrementor: [Function] }
function (bar) {
  bar++;
  privateLogger(bar);
  privateHello();
}
```

From this, it seems like myModule is now a variable that only knows what publicVar, publicCounter and publicIncrementor are. So how does it know what privateHello is? Where does that function definition exist after instantiation? It's not a part of myModule (the console.log(myModule) doesn't show it). It's not a global function (avoiding that is the point of this pattern). So where does that function definition live now?

Or is it that the privateHello function gets re-defined every time I call myModule.publicIncrementor?

Answer (score 2):

This is where **closures** pop in. The `privateHello`, `privateLogger`, `privateVar1` and `privateVar2` are scoped to your immediately invoked function, and when your `publicIncrementor` function is accessing these private variables (which are outside the `publicIncrementor` scope), a closure is created.

So, to answer your question: it lives on the closure now. About your question if it's redefined each time, I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know, a closure is recreated each time you access a variable from outside the local scope, but it doesn't redefine the objects, in stead of that it will always refer to the same objects.

There are a lot of interesting answers that cover closures, so you might want to take a look at the following answer:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Thanks, in some way what I just needed was the term to describe what's happening. So just letting me know to research closures is a pretty big help.

Comment: Also in looking at it, I was ignoring the IIFE part of this exercise, which is a big oversight as it as a scope question.

Comment: This link was very helpful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 1):

In your original code (before the question was updated) the `privateHello` was missing in the variable declaration list so your `privateHello` was actually becoming global.

Now you've added `privateHello` to the `var` list (well spotted), so it is currently just a local variable in the scope of your module constructor function.

I'll try to answer your questions now.

> From this, it seems like myModule is now a variable that only knows what publicVar, publicCounter and publicIncrementor are. So how does it know what privateHello is?

`myModule` instance does not "know" `privateHello` directly in a sense that you could somehow "reach out" to `privateHello` only having `myModule`.

But the constructor function used to create `myModule` declares `privateHello` in a local variable in its body.

> Where does that function definition exist after instantiation?

Somewhere in the memory.

> It's not a part of myModule (the console.log(myModule) doesn't show it).

It is. It is just not assigned to any property of `myModule`.

> It's not a global function (avoiding that is the point of this pattern).

Now it is not, in a previous version of your question it was.

> So where does that function definition live now?

Physically it is somewhere in the computer memory. Logically it is just a local variable in the module constructor function. Where does `privateVar1` live? They're probably neighbours with `privateHello`.

> Or is it that the privateHello function gets re-defined every time I call `myModule.publicIncrementor`?

Hard to answer without knowing the semantics of "re-defined". It will be probably the same "instance" of the function every time, but I guess this is an implementation detail. Are you worried about getting new exemplars of the locally defined function? Don't.

Comment: Yep, I did edit the question to change that. When I was running some checks in Node I was logging the global object and seeing the privateHello function, but not the privateIncrementor, and was confused. However then I realized that it was because of the missing var. I edited it because I knew the reason for what I was seeing and it wasn't really the question I was asking.

Comment: Can you tell me how I could log and inspect the text of myModule's constructor function? If I was able to do so, would I see privateHello in the output of that?

Comment: @RV Having just `myModule` instance? I think you can't. If I got your question correctly, you're asking something like "How can I get the function which returned the given object instance?". So if this is what you asking then I think you can't. There probably are tricks to do that but none that I know or use.